Simple graph $G$ can be represented as union of $2$ edge-disjoint graphs
I'm trying to prove the following statement:
Prove that any simple graph $G$ can be represented as the union of $2$ edge-disjointed graphs $G_{1}$ and $G_{2}$, where $G_{1}$ is acyclic and $G_{2}$ such that nodes on $G_{2}$ have an even degree.
I know that if $G_{1}$ is acyclic then it's fine because then $G = G_{1}$. But what if $G$ has cycles? Then I know I can remove cycles from $G$ but I don't know what to do from here on.

Your idea to "remove cycles from $G$" is essentially all that's needed.
To begin, initialize $G_1$ to have all the edges of $G$, and $G_2$ to have no edges. Now, as long as $G_1$ has a cycle, find such a cycle, remove all the edges from $G_1$, and add them to $G_2$. One can check that (i) at each step of this process, every vertex has even degree in $G_2$ (show this by induction), and (ii) once this process terminates, $G_1$ cannot have any cycles.
